# Is it possible to zip two Streams of different sizes and keep the remaining part in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have two Streams which could be finite or infinite:

```scala
val a = Stream(1, 2, 3)
val b = Stream(95, 96, 97, 98, 99)
```

I can zip them together like so:

```
left.zip(right).flatMap { case (a, b) => Stream(a, b) }
```

However, the end result would merge three elements from `a` and three from `b` (`1, 95, 2, 96, 3, 97`). What I'd like to achieve is to zip those two Streams and if one's bigger in size, append the remainder. So the output would be `1, 95, 2, 96, 3, 97, 98, 99`.

Is there a nice functional way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`zipAll`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html#zipAll[A1%3E:A,B](that:Iterable[B],thisElem:A1,thatElem:B):CC[(A1,B)]) + **Option** to do that.

```
def join[A](s1: Stream[A], s2: Stream[A]): Stream[A] =
  s1.map(a => Some(a)).zipAll(s2.map(a => Some(a)), None, None).flatMap {
    case (Some(a1), Some(a2)) => Stream(a1, a2)
    case (Some(a1), None)     => Stream(a1)
    case (None,     Some(a2)) => Stream(a2)
    case (None,     None)     => Stream.empty
  }

join(Stream(1, 2, 3), Stream(95, 96, 97, 98, 99))
// res: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 95, 2, 96, 3, 97, 98, 99)
```

*(PS: If you are in Scala `2.13` use **LazyList** instead of **Stream**)*